# View all ORACLE SQL statements run as stacktrace

Tags: oracle

I want a log of all the SQL that runs after I execute a procedure or statement.

I have used the SPOOL command which works well, HOWEVER I have multiple triggers that run after I run the spooled command which do not get logged.

Is there a way to output the SQL in the triggers?

Current simple spool code:

```
set echo on
spool c:\Test_SQL.log
-- Code Logged
spool off;
```

Comment: You can use the oracle trace facility and tkprof - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL791

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks! This looks like what I'm after, how do I change/where is the output folder after setting Session SQL_Trace to true?